# How to cast a segment of an array into an array in Go?

Tags: arrays, go, slice, sha256

I'm using the hash function `sha256.Sum256(data []byte) [sha256.Size]byte`. 
I need that the returned digest is stored at the end of another bigger array.

```
var x [sha256.BlockSize+sha256.Size]byte 
? = sha256.Sum256(data)
```

The only solution I found so far is the following:

```
var x [sha256.BlockSize+sha256.Size]byte 
var d = sha256.Sum256(data)
copy(x[sha256.BlockSize:], d[:])
```

Is it possible to avoid this copy ?

Answer (score 5):

You can avoid the copy if you abandon using the [`sha256.Sum256()`](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/sha256/#Sum256) function, and you first create a [`hash.Hash`](https://golang.org/pkg/hash/#Hash) by calling [`sha256.New()`](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/sha256/#New).

Using a `hash.Hash` you can calculate the digest using the `Hash.Sum()` method, and what's important here is that you can pass a slice to it indicating that you want the results to be appended to that.

For the target slice, you can pass a slice value pointing to the element in your `x` array where you want the result, e.g. with **0 length** (as result will be *appended* to this slice, not filled into it):

```
var x [sha256.BlockSize+sha256.Size]byte
h := sha256.New()
h.Write(data)
h.Sum(x[sha256.BlockSize:sha256.BlockSize])
```

See this example to demonstrate it:

```
data := []byte("hello")
fmt.Println(sha256.Sum256(data))

var x [sha256.BlockSize + sha256.Size]byte
h := sha256.New()
h.Write(data)
res := h.Sum(x[sha256.BlockSize:sha256.BlockSize])
fmt.Println(res)
fmt.Println(x)
```

First I print the result using `sha256.Sum256()` so we have an "authentic" result to comapre to. Then I call and print the result of `Hash.Sum()`. Last we print the `x` array to verify the result is in it.

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/OhBAZoHBVl)):

`[44 242 77 186 95 176 163 14 38 232 59 42 197 185 226 158 27 22 30 92 31 167 66 94 115 4 51 98 147 139 152 36]
[44 242 77 186 95 176 163 14 38 232 59 42 197 185 226 158 27 22 30 92 31 167 66 94 115 4 51 98 147 139 152 36]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 44 242 77 186 95 176 163 14 38 232 59 42 197 185 226 158 27 22 30 92 31 167 66 94 115 4 51 98 147 139 152 36]`

**Update:**

You wrote that you knew about this but intentionally avoided this to avoid allocating a `hash.Hash`. Know that `sha256.Sum256()` uses the same implementation that is returned by `sha256.New()` under the hood, so this solution is most likely not slower (did not benchmark). **Also you can reuse the hasher!** So in fact this can be made faster. To reuse, call the `Hash.Reset()` method.

**Update #2:**

You indicated you have to do this in every web request. In this case probably using `sha256.Sum256()` is the best choice. If you do need to boost performance, you could opt to "clone" the `sha256` package, and in your cloned version you could modify the `Sum256()` function to receive a slice where the results could be stored directly (my linked other answer shows the first step toward this), but seriously, copying 32 bytes (size of SHA-256 digest) is so fast, not worth the hassle, and performance gain would not be huge.

See related question: [How to efficiently hash (SHA 256) in golang data where only the last few bytes changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45385707/how-to-efficiently-hash-sha-256-in-golang-data-where-only-the-last-few-bytes-c/45389087#45389087)

Comment: I was aware of this. I use `sha256.Sum256()` because I want to avoid the allocation with `sha256.New()`.

Comment: @chmike Please read my edited answer. `sha256.Sum256()` uses the same hasher under the hood that is returned by `sha256.Hash()`, and you can reuse the `hash.Hash` returned by `sha256.New()`.

Comment: As far as I understand the code, `sha256.Sum256()` does not allocate a block. The digest structure is on the stack.

Comment: @chmike `sha256.Sum256()` also has to allocate the block, just that will stay on the stack. And it also has to allocate the result which won't be on the stack, which `Hash.Sum()` does not if you pass a slice. Also by reusing the `hash.Hash` I'm sure you can achieve far better performance. See the linked answer for examples and benchmarks: [How to efficiently hash (SHA 256) in golang data where only the last few bytes changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45385707/how-to-efficiently-hash-sha-256-in-golang-data-where-only-the-last-few-bytes-c/45389087#45389087).

Comment: I just checked. sha256.Sum256() has 0 allocations on the heap. The array returned is stored on the stack. Beside, my benchmarks show no significant difference with the copy. So the copy might be optimized away.

Comment: @chmike You're right, the result (digest) is stored in an array which is the return value, so it doesn't need allocation. Still, by reusing a `hash.Hash`, you're only allocating once in the lifetime of `hash.Hash`, and not once for every use.

Comment: I agree with the reuse of the hash instance. Unfortunately this is not an option for me. The use case is to encode or verify a secure cookie. I do have concurrent hashing, and hashing is performed with nearly every web request. Reducing allocations allow reduce pressure on the GC. hmac is even worse than sha because it allocates 5 blocks. I've implemented my own hmac and removed all allocation by using Sum256. Apparently it's ok to use copy.

Comment: @chmike In your case probably using `sha256.Sum256()` is the best choice. If you do need to boost performance, you could opt to "clone" the `sha256` package, and in your cloned version you could modify the `Sum256()` function to receive a slice where the results could be stored directly (my linked other answer shows the first step toward this), but seriously, copying 32 bytes is so fast, not worth the hassle and performance gain would not be huge.

Comment: I also tried that (copy sha256) but I then loose the hardware and assembly optimization. This is why I added a Go issue about Sum256() not allowing var args to compute hash on multiple slices. They are looking into it. For now I managed to avoid this limitation by concatenating data to hash into one array. This is what led me to ask the above question. So I'll use the copy now. I could eventually use unsafe pointers but importing unsafe would not give a good impression for a secure cookie package. Thanks for all the suggestions. I didn't clearly exposed my use case.